# Through windows service open browser to render and screenshot webgl page in selenium .Net

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, selenium, windows-services

I have made an application in which i have used selenium in .Net. In the code, What i did was,  using chrome driver, i opened up a url in chrome, where the page contains webgl and took a snapshot of the page. This works fine, when i run the code in visual studio, the chrome browser opens the webpage and renders the webgl page perfectly and takes a screenshot and saves to disk.

However, when i wrap this code in a windows service and invoke the service from other application , the browser window does not seem to open and even the snapshot taken says "Webgl not supported" (i have added code to show this message if webgl is not supported by the browser).

I am really confused , as the code works fine when running from visual studio, the webgl page renders ok, and when invoked from windows service say's webgl not supported.

I tried running the windows service with administrator rights as well as Local System, with interact with desktop option enabled, but didnt help.

Has anyone any idea, as what might be happening?

Here is the Code

```
Logger.Log("Step 001");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
Logger.Log("Step 002");
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnitWithJavaScript();
Logger.Log("Step 003");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Logger.Log("Step 004");
options.AddArguments("start-maximized", "no-default-browser-check", "--ignore-certificate-errors","--enable-webgl-image-chromium", "--ignore-gpu-blacklist", "--use-gl", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-web-security");
Logger.Log("Step 005");
capabilities.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, options);
Logger.Log("Step 006");
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.IsJavaScriptEnabled, true);
Logger.Log("Step 007");
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);
Logger.Log("Step 008");
IWebDriver WebDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
Logger.Log("Step 009");
WebDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
Logger.Log("Step 010");
Logger.Log("Navigating to Url");
Logger.Log("Step 011");
WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:8088/index.html");
Logger.Log("Step 012");
Logger.Log("Navigating to Url Complete");
Logger.Log("Sleeping for 10 sec.");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
Logger.Log("Sleep complete");
Logger.Log("Taking screenshot");
Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)WebDriver).GetScreenshot();
Logger.Log("Step 013");
screenshot.SaveAsFile("c:\\temp\\acd.jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
Logger.Log("Step 014");
Logger.Log("Snapshot Complete");
Logger.Log("Webdriver quit");
WebDriver.Quit();
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). It will provide you with a headless browser for Chrome.

Comment: Phantomjs doesn't support webgl , hence had to move on to selenium for this.